# How to assign a formula variable to a procedure variable in maple?

Tags: maple

I'm new in Maple and I want to do some calculations on the functions that have some parts in common. the problem is that I have to change the common part frequently and I don't want to do it by hand and using copy and paste.

I wrote this code but it doesn't work.

```
u := a*x^2+b*y^2+c*x:
f1 := proc (x, y) options operator, arrow; u+5*x end proc
f2 := proc (x, y) options operator, arrow; u+10*x end proc;
f3 := proc (x, y) options operator, arrow; u+20*x end proc;
diff(f1, x)+2*(diff(f2, x))+diff(f3, x)
```

The result is 0.

where is my mistake? 
what can I do?
Thank you for your attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that f1, f2, and f3 are operators (functions), not formulae (expressions).  There are a couple of possible solutions here.

First, replace the operators with formulae:

```
f1 := u + 5*x:
f2 := u + 10*x:
f3 := u+20*x:
diff(f1, x)+2*(diff(f2, x))+diff(f3, x);
                        8 a x + 4 c + 45
```

Second option, apply the operators:

```
diff(f1(x,y), x)+2*(diff(f2(x,y), x))+diff(f3(x,y), x);
                        8 a x + 4 c + 45
```

Note that `y` is not actually used.  The second has the advantage that changing `u` and re-evaluating will work as you probably want.

Comment: this is my code for calculating integral
u(x,y) is a function of x and y from previous calculation, but i can't assign it to f1
what can i do?     
`g1 := Matrix(1, 100);
 f1:=(x,y)->:
k := 0; for i from -1 by .2 to .8 do for j from -1 by .2 to .8 do k := k+1; g1[1, k] := f1((i+i+.2)*(1/2), (j+j+.2)*(1/2))*(i-i+.2)*(j-j+.2) end do end do;
%;
u4 := 0; for i to 100 do s1 := g1[1, i]; u4 := s1+u4 end do;`

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm really not understanding what you are trying.  As an aside, your second loop can be replaced by a call to `add`